# Define export path for swt-win32.dll and swt-win32-XXXX.dll

Tags: java, swt, jnlp, unsatisfiedlinkerror

We encountered a problem with starting of our SWT-application at certain users PCs. Application is deployed via JNLP. 
At the start

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
no swt-win32-4234 in java.library.path
no swt-win32 in java.library.path
Can't load library: C\Users\userprofile\swt-win32-4234.dll
Can't load library: C\Users\userprofile\swt-win32.dll
```

occures. Copying these files into specified folder doesn't help. We suspected, that the error might have occurred because of existence of older user profiles, but it even happens on PCs without these.

Is there any way to manually specify where these libraries shall be extracted and thus make sure, they are found?

Thanks.

Comment: Run depends.exe on the dlls and see if there are any missing dependencies

Comment: Are those certain users using 64 bit operating systems?  Java runtimes?  What about the other users?  Do you have a bitness mismatch?

Comment: Well, in our company both 32bit and 64bit systems are used, but only 32Bit Java. The most users do no have any problems, but only a few had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Versions up to and including 3.2 suffer from this issue. This is resolved by adding a 64-bit swt.jar in the \libswt\win32 to replace the 32-bit.

A better way to implement this is to create a win64 directory in libswt, copy the swt.jar file into here and modify the .bat scripts. For example, in spoon.bat find the line:

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libswt\win32\swt.jar

and change it to

set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;libswt\win64\swt.jar

Answer (score 0):

[Quote from "Pete" @ http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/229186/ ]

Had Same initial issue and finally sorted it by...

Right click on project and go to Properties

In Java Build Path under the Projects tab there is the associated Project, in my case org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86

Expand this down with the little arrow to the left to display the options. Here I found Native Library Locations. This wasn't set so I selected it and clicked Edit.

In the Popup window that follows, I selected Workspace and then org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.

Next time I ran the class, it work fine.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Actually I do not have anything under associated projects. swt.jar is built in into product jar.